# Electromagnetic Stress Energy Tensor in terms of the potential

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

On a problem, I'm working on calculating the electromagnetic force in the absence of charge distribution with Maxwell's Electric Stress Tensor.

$F=\int d^3r \nabla\cdot \stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{T}=\int d\vec{S}\cdot\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{T}$

Where

$T_{ij}=\epsilon_0(E_iE_j-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}E^2)$

Or in terms of the scalar potential

$T_{ij}=\epsilon_0([\partial_i\phi][\partial_j\phi]-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}[\partial_k\phi][\partial_k\phi])$

By taking the gradient

$\partial_iT_{ij}=\epsilon_0([\partial_i\partial_i\phi][\partial_j\phi]+[\partial_i\phi][\partial_i\partial_j\phi]-\delta_{ij}[\partial_i\partial_k\phi][\partial_k\phi])$

But since $\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=0$, the first term cancells. Applying the delta and changing the dummy index:

$\partial_iT_{ij}=\epsilon_0([\partial_i\phi][\partial_i\partial_j\phi]-[\partial_i\phi][\partial_j\partial_i\phi])=\epsilon_0([\partial_i\phi][\partial_i\partial_j\phi]-[\partial_i\phi][\partial_i\partial_j\phi])=0$

Which des not make sence, since when you do it with the surface integral, there is in fact a force.

Please help! Thank you so much!!

Comment: It seems like your problem has nothing to do with expressing things in terms of the potential, because it stems from $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E=0$. Could you try it in terms of E field alone and see if you can resolve the problem yourself?